# what (amd) script loader to use for mobile site

Tags: mobile, local-storage, requirejs, amd

I'm starting work on a new version of a mobile site.  I am looking into using an amd script loader and have pretty much narrowed it down to require and lsjs.  I know there are many pro's and con's to both, but I am trying to figure all of those out for the mobile version of my site.  Does anyone have experience with this lib's at the mobile level?  Just trying to get a discussion going here of what people think the best way to go is. (anyone with a 1500 rep want to create an lsjs tag :) ). Maybe either of the creators of these libraries (todd burke or richard backhouse) have an opinion on this

thanks

EDIT:

thanks to Simon Smith for the great info down below.  has anyone used lsjs? it looks very promising in terms of speed, but does not have the user base, documentation, or (i think) features of require/curl, but still looks very promising

Answer (score 2):

I would say use RequireJS until you're ready to go to production. Then compile your scripts and replace RequireJS with Almond. It's a bare-bones library made by James Burke (author of RequireJS) so you can rely on it to work seamlessly:

> Some developers like to use the AMD API to code modular JavaScript,
>   but after doing an optimized build, they do not want to include a full
>   AMD loader like RequireJS, since they do not need all that
>   functionality. Some use cases, like mobile, are very sensitive to file
>   sizes.
>
> By including almond in the built file, there is no need for RequireJS.
>   almond is around 1 kilobyte when minified with Closure Compiler and
>   gzipped.

https://github.com/jrburke/almond

**EDIT:**

Curl.js is also an option. I haven't used it but know that is a lot smaller than RequireJS. Did a bit of research as to why:

RequireJS does the following over Curl (via James Burke):

> - Supports multiversion/contexts, useful for mock testing, but you can get by without it
> - Supports loading plain JS files via require, does not have to be an AMD module
> - Supports special detection and work with older versions of jQuery (should not be an issue if you use jQuery 1.7.1 or later)
> - (At the moment) better support for simplified wrapped commonjs style: define(function(require) {});
>
> In short, if you are only going to deal with AMD modules in your app,
>   do not need the multiversion/context support, and are not using the
>   simplified commonjs wrapping style, or using an older jQuery, then
>   curl can be a good choice.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/requirejs/niUyLZrivgs

And the author of Curl:

> RequireJS runs in more places than curl.js, including WebWorkers and
>   node.js. It's also got more "battle testing" than curl.js, which may
>   mean it has less bugs around edge cases. curl.js is also missing a few
>   important features, such as preloading of implicit dependencies and
>   support for AMD-wrapped commonjs modules. These are both coming in
>   version 0.6 (late next week).
>
> On the plus side, curl.js...
>
> is as small as 1/4 the size of RequireJS -- even when bundled with the
>   js! and domReady! plugins it is still less than half the size.
>
> is faster at loading modules than RequireJS, but only meaningfully so in
>   IE6-8 or in development (non-build) environments.
>
> supports pluggable
>   module loaders for formats other than AMD (we're working on unwrapped
>   CJSM/1.1 and CJSM/2.0, for instance).
>
> supports configuration-based
>   dependency management via IOC containers like wire.js (via cram.js).
>
> supports inlining of css (via cram.js) and concatenation of css (via
>   cram.js 0.3 by end of year)

https://github.com/cujojs/curl/issues/35#issuecomment-2954344

Comment: yeah, this is definitely the way i would go with require.  the two things that are making me wary of this is that you no longer can do dynamic on demand loading when using almond and require does not use local storage to cache the js/css files which seems really appealing on the mobile level.  Thanks for starting the discussion!

Comment: Yes, Almond is limiting. Updated my answer with a bit more info. Hope that helps.

Comment: It's worth noting that the comments cited above are well over 2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Back in 2014 I faced the same problem.  I had some extra requirements though in order to make the site fast on mobile:

- Small enough to be inlined (to avoid paying an extra request-tax to
  get the loader onboard).
- Inlined config file (get rid of a request).
- Config file in pure javascript (no parsing overhead).
- Let the browser do the actual loading (browsers are smart these days) of files.
- Connect all asynchronously loaded modules together.
- Support for single page apps that include legacy code that uses sprinkled $(function(){...}) constructs, yet I insist on loading jQuery late and asynchronously to speed things up.

After evaluating RequireJS, curl, lsjs and a bunch of others, I concluded that none of them came close enough to what I needed for my projects.  Eventually I decided to create my own [lockandload AMD-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lockandload).  I didn't open-source it at the time, because that meant writing documentation.  But I recently open-sourced it with fresh docs in case it benefits others.