# Javascript requireJS Dependency Array as a Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

The following code works:

```
define(["./my/dependency"], function (myDep) {
    return awesomeness
    // Everything is fine :)
}
```

It would be very nice, due to restrictions in the environment I'm working in, to define dependencies earlier in an array but this doesn't work:

```
deps = ["./my/dependency"]

define(deps, function (myDep) {
    return abandonAllHope
    // Everything is terrible :(
})
```

I'm new to Javascript/requireJS/nodeJS and working to alter an existing nodeJS project. The website fails to load major elements when I try the second option. I'm not sure how to bugfix this issue and can't understand why only the second option fails.

Comment: How are you adding the dependencies to the array?

Comment: Right now just as shown, with an implicitly created array of strings. (`deps = ["./my/dependencies"]`) I was trying to do something fancier earlier, but then boiled the error down to this.

Comment: [**That doesn't seem to be the error**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12047637/). There is probably something else wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems:

- missing **var** keyword
- you are defining global variable **deps** which might be overwriting something

Please try this one, this uses anonymous function which is calling itself instance:

```
(function () {
    var deps = ["./my/dependency"];

    define(deps, function (myDep) {
        return abandonAllHope
        // Everything is terrible :(
    });
}());
```